# OpenLDAP Proxy to AD - userPrincipalName as BindDN

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I've setup OpenLDAP as AD proxy according to:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD

Everything's working fine for clients using standard *bindDN* of full *dn*: attribute (e.g. `cn=jdoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`)

Some of the clients are using *userPrincipalName* as *bindDN*, which is perfectly ok with AD, but not with the OpenLDAP proxy, which throws an error upon connect:

```
conn=1002 op=1 do_bind: invalid dn (jdoe@example.com)  
send_ldap_result: conn=1002 op=1 p=3  
send_ldap_result: err=34 matched="" text="invalid DN"  
send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=97 err=34  
conn=1002 op=1 RESULT tag=97 err=34 text=invalid DN
```

I tried to rewrite the *bindDN* of *userPrincipalName* using `rwm-rewriteRule` from the `rwm` overlay. That didn't work, although it works with standard bind *dn's*(e.g.`cn=jdoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`)

This doesn't work:

```
rwm-rewriteRule "(.+,)@example.com$" "cn=$1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"  ":"
```

This works - rewriting `ou=users` for `ou=employees` as a test:

```
rwm-rewriteRule "(.+,)?ou=users,dc=example,dc=com$" "$1ou=employees,dc=example,dc=com"  ":"
```

Is there a way how to rewrite *bindDN* of *jdoe@example.com* to *bindDN* of *cn=jdoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com*?

Thanks for any ideas :)

Here's my current config:

```
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema  
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema  
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema  
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema  
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema  

modulepath              /usr/lib64/openldap/  
moduleload              back_ldap  
moduleload              rwm  

pidfile                 /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid  
argsfile                /var/run/openldap/slapd.args  

database                ldap  
readonly                yes  
protocol-version        3  
rebind-as-user          yes  
uri                     "ldap://X.X.X.X:389"  
suffix                  "dc=example,dc=com"  
overlay                 rwm  
rwm-rewriteEngine on  
rwm-rewriteRule "(.+,)@example.com$" "cn=$1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"  ":"  
logfile                 /var/log/slapd/slapd.log  
loglevel                -1  
TLSCACertificatePath /etc/openldap/certs  
TLSCertificateFile "OpenLDAP Server"  
TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/openldap/certs/password
```

Comment: This is a updated duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/949699/openldap-userprincipalname-as-binddn. Please update this question instead of 949699. Thank you.